# How to export displayfield contents to an excel sheet in extjs?

Tags: extjs, panel, export-to-excel, export-to-csv, displayfield

I have a set of displayfield contents as shown in the picture. I need to create a button when on clicking should export the contents to an excel sheet. Please guide me through this.

Note, I don't have the content as grid and hence, I want an approach which could do the same.

Contents in the panel
[image]

Comment: You are expecting this only by use of extjs or with some other technology?

Comment: This is not possible with pure ExtJS. You are maybe searching for [XSLX.js](https://github.com/stephen-hardy/xlsx.js).

Comment: Only extjs. Actually there are some options to convert grid data to excel or whatever document we need. But I no where saw some implementation for exporting datafield values to any file. @Tejas

Comment: @Alexander Oh, so could not export this into any file?

Comment: @Rev you can always export somehow, **by coding everything manually**. Considering the size of the XSLX standardization document (6000+ pages), this may take months (ZIP/UnZIP not included). Or you can add XSLX.js to your dependency list and get a Microsoft JavaScript library that can read and write XSLX files for you.